# Transformar dataframe en objeto JSON con jsonlite utilizando R

Tags: javascript, json, r

Intento transformar un data.frame en un objeto JSON, incluyo la estructura de la tabla de datos, el código R que utiliza la función `toJSON()` del package jsonlite, el resultado obtenido y el resultado esperado. He hecho varias combinaciones en la función, pero no encuentro la solución.

El data.frame tiene esta estructura, lo he resumido para no volcar todos los datos:

```
structure(list(`Código Municipio INE` = c("02003", "03014"), Municipio = c("Albacete", "Alicante/Alacant"), `Esfuerzo Social por Habitante` = c(66.255518296917, 
55.4505971732305), `Relevancia Esfuerzo Social` = c(0.0779438999416286, 
0.075567624299619), `Umbral Pobreza` = c(21, 
28.8), `Umbral Pobreza Hombres` = c(20.5, 29), `Umbral Pobreza Mujeres` = c(21.5, 28.6)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-2L))
```

Utilizo jsonlite para la transformación:

```
toJSON( 
 list(
  list(
   name = dfon$Municipio,
   data = list(
    dfon[, which(colnames(dfon) != "Municipio")],
    x = dfon$`Esfuerzo Social por Habitante`,
    y = dfon$`Umbral Pobreza`,
    size = dfon$`Relevancia Esfuerzo Social`
   )
  )
 ), pretty=TRUE)
```

El resultado que obtengo es este:

```
[
  {
    "name": ["Albacete", "Alicante/Alacant"],
    "data": {
      "1": [
        {
          "Código Municipio INE": "02003",
          "Esfuerzo Social por Habitante": 66.2555,
          "Relevancia Esfuerzo Social": 0.0779,
          "Umbral Pobreza": 21,
          "Umbral Pobreza Hombres": 20.5,
          "Umbral Pobreza Mujeres": 21.5
        },
        {
          "Código Municipio INE": "03014",
          "Esfuerzo Social por Habitante": 55.4506,
          "Relevancia Esfuerzo Social": 0.0756,
          "Umbral Pobreza": 28.8,
          "Umbral Pobreza Hombres": 29,
          "Umbral Pobreza Mujeres": 28.6
        }
      ],
      "x": [66.2555, 55.4506],
      "y": [21, 28.8],
      "size": [0.0779, 0.0756]
    }
  }
]
```

Pero necesito un formato como este, es decir, para cada registro deben haber dos claves, name y data:

```
[
  {
    "name":"Albacete",
    "data":[
      {
        "Código Municipio INE":"02003",
        "Municipio":"Albacete",
        "Esfuerzo Social por Habitante":66.255518296917,
        "Relevancia Esfuerzo Social":0.0779438999416286,
        "Umbral Pobreza":21,
        "Umbral Pobreza Hombres":20.5,
        "Umbral PobrezaMujeres":21.5,
        "x":66.255518296917,
        "y":21,
        "size":7.79438999416286,
      }
    ]
  },

  {
    "name":"Alicante/Alacant",
    "data":[
      {
        "Código Municipio INE":"03014",
        "Municipio":"Alicante/Alacant",
        "Esfuerzo Social por Habitante":55.4505971732305,
        "Relevancia Esfuerzo Social":0.075567624299619,
        "Umbral Pobreza":28.8,
        "Umbral Pobreza Hombres":29,
        "Umbral Pobreza Mujeres":28.6,
        "x":55.4505971732305,
        "y":28.8,
        "size":7.5567624299619,
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Llamo a tu datos `df`

```
df %>% 
  group_by(Municipio) %>% 
  rename(name = Municipio) %>% 
  nest() %>% 
  toJSON(pretty = TRUE)
```

Y obtengo:

```
[
  {
    "name": "Albacete",
    "data": [
      {
        "Código Municipio INE": "02003",
        "Esfuerzo Social por Habitante": 66.2555,
        "Relevancia Esfuerzo Social": 0.0779,
        "Umbral Pobreza": 21,
        "Umbral Pobreza Hombres": 20.5,
        "Umbral Pobreza Mujeres": 21.5
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "Alicante/Alacant",
    "data": [
      {
        "Código Municipio INE": "03014",
        "Esfuerzo Social por Habitante": 55.4506,
        "Relevancia Esfuerzo Social": 0.0756,
        "Umbral Pobreza": 28.8,
        "Umbral Pobreza Hombres": 29,
        "Umbral Pobreza Mujeres": 28.6
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

No estoy muy familiarizado con json, así que quizás algo esté mal. Pero se parece mucho a lo que buscas.

La clave es armar la estructura de datos en R. En este caso funcionó mejor un nested data.frame que una lista a secas. Creo que se podría hacer con listas, pero me parece que sería más complicado. Mirando la ayuda de `toJSON` encontré que admitía nested data.frames. Es una estructura que uso poco, pero a veces sirve de mucho.